# Confused about haskell 'maybe', can someone pls help me?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

My selfmade datatype Location is defined below:

```
data Location = Location String Int
```

And my required function looks like this:

```
Function:: String-> Maybe Location
Funtion s
    |head(s)`elem`['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'] && last(s) `elem`['1','2','3','4'] = Just Location head(s) digitToInt(last(s))
    |otherwise = Nothing
```

However when I try to run in terminal, it shows this:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘([a0] -> a0)
                              -> String -> (Char -> Int) -> Char -> Maybe Location’
            with actual type ‘Maybe (String -> Int -> Location)’
The function ‘Just’ is applied to five arguments,
but its type ‘(String -> Int -> Location)
              -> Maybe (String -> Int -> Location)’
has only one
```

Comment: you need proper parens. `Just` takes one argument.

Comment: `Just Location head(s) digitToInt(last(s))` calls `Just` passing 5 arguments: `Location, head, s, digitToIns, (last s)`. Add parentheses, and note that a function call is best written as `(f x)`, not `f(x)`.

Comment: Do you intend to have a string like `"AZ3"` produce `Just (Location "A" 3)`, or would that just be a side effect of using `head` and `last`? I would use more pattern matching: `f [s, n] = ...; f_ = Nothing`.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax

```
f x y
```

means to apply function `f` to arguments `x` and `y`. Notice that no parentheses are needed to call `f`. However, if `x` and `y` were themselves complicated expressions, they may need parentheses to group the parts of that expression together into a single argument. Suppose I want to apply `f` to the arguments `g v` and `h w`. Contrast:

```
f g v h w -- f applied to g, v, h, and w; not what I wanted
f (g v) (h w) -- f applied to (g v) and (h w); what I wanted
```

Since parentheses only group expressions, and are not themselves part of the function call syntax, that means we also have:

```
f g (v) h (w) -- f applied to g, (v), h, and (w)
f g(v) h(w) -- still f applied to g, (v), h, and (w)
```

So, when you write

```
Just Location head(s) digitToInt(last(s))
```

that means to apply `Just` to five arguments, namely, `Location`, `head`, `(s)`, `digitToInt`, and `(last(s))`. Probably not what you intended!

Hopefully this gives you enough information to take a second stab at parenthesizing things to mean what you intended.

Comment: I have to say, "I understand trying to explain things to beginners, but the code in this answer is misleading. `Just` does not take that many arguments. In fact, it takes
   only one argument. Your code is just plain wrong." and if you protest that you already talk about that in the answer and only show this code in order for the OP to learn while fixing it, then, that exactly applies to my last haskell answer and your comments there. so I just took the lesson you taught me there to heart, and applied it here. :)

Comment: @WillNess I did not write the code in this answer... at least, not the code you are referring to.

Comment: You are ignoring what I'm trying to tell you just like you've ignored my clarifying comments on that answer. I am really baffled by all this.

Comment: @WillNess I am not ignoring you. I think there is a legitimate difference between "Thing X that you said is incorrect in such-and-such way" and "A solution to your problem is X" (where X has bad code in it).

Comment: as I said to you there in the comments, my intention in that answer was "you can do it to. let's think out loud together."

Comment: ignoring not me, but the point I'm making.